# R: Consolidate different spellings of the same entry into one

Tags: r, sorting, package, misspelling

I have a data set that is sorted by company names. Sometimes the names are misspelled and show as unique entries:

```
Name
ABC Company
ABc Company
DEF Company
def compANY
Ddf Cmpany
abC comPany
```

In fact, these entries are variations of the same two company names. This is clearly a problem with my initial data set but I need to take care of it to process my data correctly.

```
Name
ABC Company
DEF Company
```

I don't know how I can approach this, other than long loops that test modified versions of the words against a dictionary-like data structure. Is there a library for spellchecking (and would that even make sense for company names)?

I'd appreciate any help and don't have a preference for any package. 
Thank you.

Comment: How does one know that there is no company called `Ddf Cmpany`?   Do you have a list of all possible companies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `adist` to get the *Approximate String Distances* which can be used in `hclust` to get clusters which can be classified in groups with `cutree`.

```
hc <- hclust(as.dist(adist(Name, ignore.case = TRUE)))
Name[!duplicated(cutree(hc,k=2))] #For two groups
#[1] "ABC Company" "DEF Company"
```

Data:

```
Name <- c("ABC Company","ABc Company","DEF Company","def compANY","Ddf Cmpany","abC comPany")
```

Comment: Thanks @GKi, that helps!